# Adding button below text in ExpandableTexVew

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I would like to know if there is a way to add a button, or any element below the text of an `ExpantableTextView`. I'm using this [library](http://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView) and I want it to look like this:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd chosen wrong library. You chose`ExpandableTextView` and now you're asking for help, because you cannot add a button to this `View`.

Try to search for `ExpandableLayout` library. Maybe this you would find useful - please check: https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout

For more similar libraries, check: http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=expandable

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

In one line Yes, it can be done in this way. 
Two approach:

1. Modifying the existing library to fulfill your need. For this you should have knowledge of building custom view.
2. This is just a work around to get the desire result. Put a `Button` with visibility set to as `invisible` and place it just below your `expandableTextView`. Now on click of your `expandableTextView` just set the visibility of your `Button` to `visible`

I hope you would be able to achieve what you want.